# MS Access Table Relationship Dropdown Behavior in Queries/Forms/Reports

Tags: database, ms-access, user-interface, subquery, relationships

I have a small question regarding access. When you create two tables and specify a particular relationship (e.g. one to many) and enforce referential integrity, when you access the table that corresponds to the "one" you get a small "+" icon on the side that will show you all the entries in the "many" table that correspond to the "one".

Is there any way to emulate this in designing a query? such that for each entry, you can expand them to show the results of a subquery involving each individual result of the main query?

You can do something similar already, but it would look like this

Assuming Table1Entry1 corresponds to Table2Entry1 and Table2Entry2 while Table1Entry2 corresponds to Table2Entry3 and Table2Entry4

this is what it would look like once you view the query results

Table1Entry1 Table2Entry1
Table1Entry1 Table2Entry2
Table1Entry2 Table2Entry3
Table1Entry2 Table2Entry4

when what I want is something like

Table1Entry1
-> Table2Entry1
   -> Table2Entry2
Table1Entry2
   -> Table2Entry3
   -> Table2Entry4

If it's not possible when designing a Query, that's fine. But is it possible to generate something like this for reports or forms?

I know this is mainly a cosmetic thing, but it would be much nicer and intuitive compared to the alternatives

Answer (score 1):

It's termed [Subdatasheet](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/add-a-subdatasheet-HA010266800.aspx#BM2)

1. In Datasheet view, open the table or query where you want to add the
   subdatasheet.
2. On the Home tab, in the Records group, click More, point to
   Subdatasheet, and then click Subdatasheet.
3. In the Insert Subdatasheet dialog box, select the tab (Tables,
   Queries, or Both) that corresponds to the type of object that you
   want to insert as a subdatasheet.
4. In the Link Child Fields box, click the field that you want to use
   as the foreign key or matching field that will provide data for the
   subdatasheet.
5. In the Link Master Fields box, click the field that you want to use
   as the primary key or matching field for the main table or query,
   and then click OK.

   NOTE    The values in the Link Child Fields and Link Master Fields boxes create a one-to-many join on the specified fields.
6. To display the subdatasheet that you added to your table, query, or
   form, click the + sign.

   NOTE   The child (foreign key) field does not appear as a column of the subdatasheet. When you add a new record in the subdatasheet, Access automatically inserts the primary key value of the selected base-table.